Firebase Analytics crash with refuse connection, how to fix it?
I got issue in crashlytrics:
failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 443) from /127.0.0.1 (port 56326) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

private const val BASE_FIREBASE_URL = "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect"

interface AnalyticsApi {
    @POST(BASE_FIREBASE_URL)
    @Headers(
        value = [
            "${ParseHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE}: application/json",
        ],
    )
    suspend fun logEvent(
        @Query("firebase_app_id") firebaseAppId: String,
        @Query("api_secret") apiSecret: String,
        @Body events: FirebaseEvent,
    )
}

I also add this lines to prevent issue, but it's not help:
install(HttpTimeout) {
    requestTimeoutMillis = 300000
    connectTimeoutMillis = 300000
    socketTimeoutMillis = 300000
}

It happened sometimes to users, but I can't catch the issue by myself. Seems like I missing something when sending analytics events
